# Evaluate $\iiint_V \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\, dV$ where $V: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 2z$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, stokes-theorem

> Evaluate $$I=\iiint_V \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\, dV\,,$$ where $V: x^2 + y^2 +
> z^2 \leq 2z$.

I tried using the cylindrical coordinates to arrive at:

$$I = \int\int_R\int_{z=1-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{1+\sqrt{1-r^2}}r\cdot\sqrt{r^2+z^2}\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$$ where $R = r \leq 1$

But this is very tough to evaluate. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not spherical coordinates?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spherical coordinates we have that

$$x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 2z \implies \rho \leq 2\cos\phi$$

so let's set up in the integral in this coordinate system. As an added bonus, let's do the angular integral first:

$$I = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 \int_0^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho}{2}\right)} \rho^3\sin\phi \:d\phi \:d\rho \:d\theta  = 2\pi\int_0^2\rho^3-\frac{1}{2}\rho^4\:d\rho = \frac{8\pi}{5}$$